# NSString removing single quote in string

Tags: iphone, nsstring

This should be simple but it's not working. I am trying to strip single quote marks from an NSString named parms using the following (stripped of non-relevant vars in the format string):

```
NSString *newVar =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [parms stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@""]];
```

So if parms contains "Mike's Hat" I would expect that newVar would contain "Mikes Hat". Instead it contains "Mike's Hat".

Comment: Maybe it's a smart quote, e.g. ’ instead of '?

Comment: It's the quote that is part of the iPhone device name. As in, "Mike's iPhone" which is derived from [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There must be more to your code than you are proving, but the following works perfectly:

```
NSString *parms = @"Mike's Hat";
NSString *newVar =[parms stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"’" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@",newVar);
```

**Output:** Mikes Hat

There could be a possibility that the character **`'`** may not be the same character in your parms string if the above does not work for you.

Turns out, you are using the wrong character copy/paste this character into your string: **`’`**

Comment: NSString *x = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
    NSString *newVar =[x stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@",newVar); This returns Mike's iPhone.

Comment: Turns out, you are using the wrong character copy/paste this character into your string: **`’`**

Comment: I’m creating a graphic from fonts and one font that I use adds a space before a smart quote. I used this to substitute a regular quote and it handles that fine. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents on this same problem I had in my code.... When I used the single quote on the keyboard to type ' into my code it didn't work. But I was printing string values to the console. When I copied and pasted the ' character from the console into my code it then worked. What is weird is that I'm using the same key on the keyboard to enter the string into a UITextField so I really don't know why the same key gets turned into something different but that's how I solved it.

Comment: Please write quality answers, once you have enough reputation. you can comment on every posts.
This one should have been a comment. not an answer.

Comment: I'm not allowed to comment so there is no other way for me to share how I solved this same problem and I thought it might help others.

Comment: That's exactly what I said, _write quality answers_ so that you can get upvotes and earn enough reputation to be able to comment everywhere